# Errors during boot in 22.4.2

Tags: boot, grub2, 22.04, helpfile

I dont know why but every time i boot in ubuntu

This is the error message that I getting plzz help solve this
[image: error]

And plzzz help me with my last question
Too

Comment: Afterwards, does the Ubuntu graphical interface (e.g. the login screen) open, or are you stuck at this error? If you can open the graphical interface, is everything working?

Comment: Since it says recovering journal, it seems that the computer was not shut down properly (might happen if it was in sleep mode and ran out of battery)

Comment: yes i am able to login , and yes maybe this could be the reason earlier my pc didnt shut down correctly

Comment: Shut down/restart properly, and check if it it again comes up

Comment: No it doesnt ,thanks btw

Comment: I have written the  comment as an answer, which you can accept.

Answer (score 0):

The messages `Recovering Journal` and `clearing orphan node` imply that the computer was not shut down properly. Shutting the computer down/restarting it will solve the issue.